# Text File not oppening in C

Tags: c, file

I need to open this file, but it isn't opening and I dont know why:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void copy();

int main(void)
{
    copy();

    return 0;
}

void copy()
{
    FILE *src = fopen("srcc.txt", "r+");

    if(!src)
    {
        printf("It was not possible to open the file");
        return;
    }
}
```

It just pass the if condition and appear the message `it was not possible to open the file` and the file is not created.

Comment: you are opening the file for reading. Thus the file must exist. Make sure you have `srcc.txt` in your current directory. If you want to create a file you need to open it in write or append mode

Comment: oh, I thought that with "r+" the OS would create the file if it didn't exist. Thank you very much

Comment: Obligatory: always check `errno` or use `perror` and include what they tell you in your C questions involving failing syscalls.

Comment: Bonus points for using [`libexplain`](http://libexplain.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: `"r+ -- read/update: Open a file for update (both for input and output). The file must exist."` -- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: btw, if this was the problem, let me know i will post an answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [***errno***](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/?kw=errno) and [***strerror()***](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strerror/) to get a specific error code. For [***fopen()***](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) on most library implementations, the errno variable is also set to a system-specific error code on failure.

You could try something like:

```
#include <errno.h>
...
...
FILE *src = fopen("srcc.txt", "r+");
if(!src)
{
    printf("ERROR: %d - %s\n", errno, strerror(errno)); // <---- This will print out some 
                                                        // useful debug info for you
    printf("It was not possible to open the file");
    return;
}
```

`errno.h` will have a list of defines for the common error codes and `strerror()` will convert the `errno` to a string that you can print out...

Likely codes you might see, in this case, include some of the following (just copied verbatim from errno.h - i left out the actual values...):

```
#define EPERM  /* Operation not permitted */
#define ENOENT /* No such file or directory */
...
#define EACCES /* Permission denied */
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file exists, it's probably read-only ... you can't use "r+" on a file that isn't writable. Do you really need "r+" and not just "r"?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are it can't find the file. I suggest making various copies of the file and putting them in various folders.

Comment: Really? What folders do you suggest?

Comment: Where your project is. I know it's ridiculous to do this, but hell I've done it more times than I can count. See because you're referencing the file simply by "srcc.txt" I'm guessing it's looking for it in the default folder. Now if you don't know which folder that is exactly, just paste the file in various folders of the project as well as the subfolders.

Comment: "I know it's ridiculous to do this" -- indeed. "but hell I've done it more times than I can count" -- sorry to hear it. Perhaps you should have spent that time understanding where the current directory of your program is. Here's a thought: *write* a file and see where it ends up.

Comment: Well after the second attempt I did learn where it was. But then in different languages and platforms it behaved differently. Gosh you don't have to be so patronising.